# Циклические операции на jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть кнопки. Как узнать,то это кнопка? В классе присутствует "knopka". Точное количество кнопок не известно. Возьму пример с двумя кнопками:

```html
<a class="knopka btn"  data-knopka="222222222" onclick="">Закрыть</a>
<div data-knopka="1111111" onclick="" class="knopka btn btn-danger">Выполнить действие</div>
```

Нужно выполнить код `jquery` который вставит данные из атрибута `data-knopka` в `onclick`, я пробовал таким кодом, но он вставляет во все кнопки одно и тоже "1111111"

```js
$(".knopka").each(function() {
  if ($(this).attr("data-knopka") != undefined) {
    console.log($(this).attr("data-knopka"));
    $(".knopka").attr("onclick", $(this).attr("data-knopka") + " return false;");
  }
})
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(".knopka").attr("onclick", $(this).attr("data-knopka") + " return false;");
```

тут вы всем элементам с классом `knopka` в атрибут `data-knopka` вставляете текущее значение, в итоге в конце вы вставите значение из последнего элемента.

Замените этот код на :

```
$(this).attr("onclick", $(this).attr("data-knopka") + " return false;");
```

```js
$(".knopka").each(function() {
  if ($(this).attr("data-knopka") != undefined) {
    console.log($(this).attr("data-knopka"));
    $(this).attr("onclick", $(this).attr("data-knopka") + " return false;");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="knopka btn" data-knopka="222222222" onclick="">Закрыть</a>
<div data-knopka="1111111" onclick="" class="knopka btn btn-danger">Выполнить действие</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Большинство функций jQuery устанавливающих значение, могут принимать в качестве параметра функцию возвращающую новое значение и принимающее старое.

Функция `attr` не является исключением: [`.attr( attributeName, function )`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function).

Код может принять следующий вид:

```js
$(".knopka[data-knopka]").attr('onclick', function(index, oldValue) {
  return $(this).attr("data-knopka") + " return false;";
});
```

```css
[data-knopka]::after {
  content: attr(onclick);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="knopka btn" data-knopka="222222222" onclick="">Закрыть </a>
<div data-knopka="1111111" onclick="" class="knopka btn btn-danger">Выполнить действие </div>
```